# PostgreSQL - Join three tables and add conditions?

Tags: postgresql

I've got three tables in a PostgreSQL db that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bNke.jpg

One user can belong to many projects, and one project can have many users, and I'm tying it together through a joined table called "userprojects".

Each table could look like this:

`User`

```
| id | firstname | lastname | email          |
|----|-----------|----------|----------------|
| 1  | Joe       | Green    | joe@green.com  |
| 2  | Olle      | Svensson | olle@gmail.com |
| 3  | Erik      | Yapp     | erik@yapp.com  |
```

`Project`

```
| id | name          | owner          |
|----|---------------|----------------|
| 1  | Project X     | joe@green.com  |
| 2  | Peanut Butter | olle@gmail.com |
| 3  | Apollo 11     | erik@yapp.com  |
| 4  | RCPP          | erik@yapp.com  |
```

`Userprojects`

```
| id | user_id | project_id |
|----|---------|------------|
| 1  | 1       | 1          |
| 2  | 1       | 2          |
| 3  | 2       | 3          |
| 4  | 3       | 3          |
```

Is there some form of inner(?) join that let's me query on users in a project (eg user_id found in `userprojects`) OR if the user is an owner of a project?

With the example above, an inner join query that looks like this:

```
SELECT "project".id, "project".name, "email" 
FROM userprojects 
INNER JOIN project ON userprojects.project_id = project.id 
INNER JOIN "user" ON userprojects.user_id = "user".id
```

would return this:

```
| id | name          | email          |
|----|---------------|----------------|
| 1  | Project X     | joe@green.com  |
| 2  | Peanut Butter | joe@green.com  |
| 3  | Apollo 11     | olle@gmail.com |
| 4  | Apollo 11     | erik@yapp.com  |
```

What I wish to add to the query result is also the owner of each project if they are not found in that inner join query - notice that `erik@yapp.com` is the owner of project `RCPP` but since that relation is not found in the `userprojects` table, it won't be returned in the query. Can I somehow also get my query to return those users, eg:

```
| id  | name          | email          |
|-----|---------------|----------------|
| 1   | Project X     | joe@green.com  |
| 2   | Peanut Butter | joe@green.com  |
| 3   | Apollo 11     | olle@gmail.com |
| 4   | Apollo 11     | erik@yapp.com  |
| (?) | RCPP          | erik@yapp.com  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the joins with the table `Project` and turn them to `LEFT` joins:

```
SELECT 
 "project".id, "project".name, 
 COALESCE("User"."email", "project"."owner") "owner" 
FROM project
LEFT JOIN userprojects  ON userprojects.project_id = project.id 
LEFT JOIN "User" ON userprojects.user_id = "User".id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwTyRTjQjysFv3cqu3k8ve/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name          | owner          |
| --- | ------------- | -------------- |
| 1   | Project X     | joe@green.com  |
| 2   | Peanut Butter | joe@green.com  |
| 3   | Apollo 11     | olle@gmail.com |
| 3   | Apollo 11     | erik@yapp.com  |
| 4   | RCPP          | erik@yapp.com  |
```

Comment: Hmm.. this changes the structure of the query - if a `user_id` is added to a project in `userprojects` (even if that user is not the owner), the query will show that added user as the owner

Comment: Your code contains "email"  in the results and I kept it. Is this that you want? Or just project.owner?

Comment: So, if you try to add user 3 to project 2 in the `userprojects` table - I'd like that to appear in the query as well - even though `erik@yapp.com` is not the owner of project `Peanut Butter`

Comment: Oh, you're right, it does, I can't get it to work in my local postgres DB though - could it have to do something with not showing the unique values? The db-fiddle looks correct but when I do it in the terminal I only get the unique ids seeing as I've got the `id` in the `project` table set to unique

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second `INNER JOIN` with the table `user` but this

time matching the `email` column of the `user` table to the `owner` of the `project` table.

```
SELECT p.id, P.name, email, CONCAT(u2.firstname, " ", u.lastname) as owner
FROM userprojects up
INNER JOIN project p ON(up.project_id = p.id)
INNER JOIN user u ON(up.user_id = u.id)
INNER JOIN user u2 ON(u2.email = p.owner)
```

Comment: The thing is, I wish to add all users to the result - if they are an owner of the project or their `user_id` exists in the `userprojects` table

Comment: @erikvm So if a user is the owner of a project and they are a member of another project, their name would appear twice?